# passing 2 values from php to ajax from 2 different text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass to values from input text to ajax but I keep getting `null` when I decode it.
Here is what I have written.

```
<script>
function myAjax() 
{
 var username = $("#username").val();
 var orderid = $("#orderid").val();

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'jumper.php',
           data:{ data1:{"username": username, "orderid": orderid}},
           datatype: 'json',
           success:function(html) 
           { 
             document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html;
           }

      });
}
</script>

<body>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<input type="text" id="orderid" name="orderid">
<button id="btnkey" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="myAjax();return false;"><span>SEARCH</span></button>

<div id="test" class="test"></div>
</body>
```

and to decode:

```
$vars = (json_decode($_POST['data1']));
echo $vars;
```

I keep getting `null` here.

Comment: It's not JSON you received through the `$_POST` variable, you need to return JSON for the AJAX call. Just try to see what you get in `$_POST` first.

Comment: Try debug what you get in `$_POST['data1']` do `echo $_POST['data1'];` or `print_r($_POST['data1']);` then decide what you wanna do, if you are not getting anything in POST then you might change your Ajax request code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send JSON, you have to call `JSON.stringify()`

```
data: { data1: JSON.stringify({"username": username, "orderid": orderid}) },
```

But you can leave it as is and just use

```
$username = $_POST['data1']['username'];
$orderid = $_POST['data1']['orderid'];
```

It's not clear why you feel the need for the `data1` property in the first place.

Other issues:

`datatype: 'json'` should be `dataType: 'json'` -- JavaScript is case-sensitive.

`echo $vars;` should be `var_dump($vars);`, since `$vars` is an array.

And neither of these will echo JSON, as expected by the `dataType` option.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep this data in $.ajax

```
data:{ data1:{"username": username, "orderid": orderid}},
```

like this

```
data:{"username": username, "orderid": orderid},
```

you will get the post data like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$orderid = $_POST['orderid'];
```

this will reduce code like you will not have to deal with JSON